# Reduce size of result sets in Salesforce Bulk API

Tags: api, bulk-api

Is it possible to reduce the size of the retrieved files in the Salesforce Bulk API. Currently it creates multiple files with a maximum size of 1Gb. I would like to reduce that limit to ~100Mb. The obvious solution is to do multiple queries but it would be a lot simpler if the batches could be limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current infrastructure of Bulk API does not allows user to split result from one query.
So the only option is to fire multiple queries.

[Bulk API Query - Splitting large query into batches](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/bulk-api-query-splitting-large-query-into-batches)

Comment: I ended up streaming the request and processing on the fly. It's a pretty cool solution because now it doesn't matter what size the receiving file is.